# Configuring debugger in Intellij Idea with Jetty

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

I am unable to configure intellij idea debugger with jetty. I have jetty 1.8. I created debug configuration following configuration on jetbrains site. I ran the debugger it deployed my artifact but when i hit the server i get service unavailable. I saw the logs and it says no class def found for any of my class files in lib. I restarted the debugger but this time it says 'server not connected, please click deploy'. After clicking deploy same message is shown again and again. But when I hit the server now i can see my homepage. But debugger is not activated. Now if I restart debugger It doesn't get restarted. And even after I closed idea still jetty is running behind because I can still hit my homepage. I've no clue of all this weird things happening. Please if someone could provide with detailed configuration for configuring idea with jetty for debugging. Thanks
I'm using windows 7, with idea 11 and jdk 1.7

Comment: OS, IDEA, Java versions? Make sure artifact has all the dependencies: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.

Comment: windows7, jdk1.7, idea 11. I have all the dependencies. I was able to easily configure debugging with resin.

Comment: Make sure it's IDEA 11.1.3 and vanilla Jetty installation. If you can still reproduce the problem, please share a sample project.

Comment: Nothing is working. Fed up with this. Using resin now.